# Query to extract Subscribers and what lists they are on

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views

I need to extract Subscriber details and the List details they are on.

My below query is working but how can I  narrow it to see who has signed up on the website in 2017 and has never been sent an email?

```
select l.ListID, l.ListName, l.EmailAddress, l.AddMethod,l.Addedby, l.CreatedDate, a.first_name_o, a.last_name_o, l.DateUnsubscribed, l.Status,a.job_title_o, a.library_type_o, S.EventDate

from ent._EnterpriseAttribute a
LEFT join _ListSubscribers l on a._SubscriberID = l.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN _Sent S on  a._SubscriberID = S.SubscriberID
where ListName <> 'All Subscribers'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in this **[doc](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_subscribers/)** you can use the **DateJoined** field from the **Subscribers** data view to filter your results:

```
select l.ListID, l.ListName, l.EmailAddress, l.AddMethod,l.Addedby, l.CreatedDate, a.first_name_o, a.last_name_o, l.DateUnsubscribed, l.Status,a.job_title_o, a.library_type_o, S.EventDate

from ent._EnterpriseAttribute a
LEFT join _ListSubscribers l on a._SubscriberID = l.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN _Sent S on  a._SubscriberID = S.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers  subs on  a._SubscriberID = subs.SubscriberID
where ListName <> 'All Subscribers' AND DATEPART (year ,subs.DateJoined) > 2017
```

Comment: Actually it's not populating 'DateJoined' value at all for any Subscribers. '_Subscriber' is vanilla System view right. Is there any possibility that we are not using it in our Account?

Comment: @Amulya, according to the documentation DateJoined can be nullable. Try this one CreatedDate on _ListSubscribers.

Comment: It was my mistake. I am running this query on child BU and forgot to prefix with ent. on _Subscribers. Now it's working, thanks for the help.!!